# Neovim scp doesn't prompt for password

Tags: vim, scp, neovim

In Vim, this prompts me for a password allowing me to edit a remote file:

```
:e scp://username@host//path
```

Yet, using the same command with NeoVim doesn't prompt for a password because the underlying command `:! scp user@host:path LOCAL-TEMPFILE` does not work interactively in NeoVim: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#-and-system-do-weird-things-with-interactive-processes

What is the best practice to edit a remote file with NeoVim that has password authentication over ssh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that the *netrw* plugin that provides this functionality isn't installed / active for Neovim. Check whether the `:Nread` command is available. Compare the `:scriptnames` output from Vim and Neovim. Read the plugin's documentation `:help pi_netrw` for how to install and enable it.

Update: So, it turns out that there's an [Neovim issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#-and-system-do-weird-things-with-interactive-processes) with interactive commands started from `:!`, and this is what netrw is doing; the plugin does not capture the password challenge. It's basically executing `:! scp user@host:path LOCAL-TEMPFILE`

If you can avoid the issue (use key-based SSH authentication for the hosts), you could continue to use Neovim with netrw. If this is really important to you, more elaborate workarounds are possible. (For example, I use a wrapper around `ssh` that parses `~/.ssh/config` for custom `Password Hunter2` entries (these passwords are well known in the org and only used for testing VMs, so no security issue here), and then uses `sshpass` to automatically log in.)

Else, you have to switch to classic Vim for netrw operations, or use another way of accessing these remote files (e.g. *SSHFS*).

Comment: netrw and :Nread gives a shell exit of 1.  So, the underlying command is `scp 'user@host:path' '/some/temp/path'`; In vim there is a prompt for the password, yet with nvim there is no prompt for the password, instead I see 3 "attempts" to login with ssh. So it seems that the issue lies with capturing the password challenge

Comment: Ah, that's important information that you should add to your question.

Comment: The netrw plugin does not capture the password challenge. It's basically executing `:! scp user@host:path LOCAL-TEMPFILE`. Please try that command manually in nvim. If there's no password prompt, something's wrong with nvim.

Comment: I guess the issue is that `:! [cmd]` does not work interactively in neovim https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#-and-system-do-weird-things-with-interactive-processes

Comment: Ah, good find; I think you're right! Unfortunately, that only leaves some workarounds. I've extended my answer with the findings, and some recommendations. Please accept if you agree with them.